# How can I use findOne method in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Firstly, I am new in Meteor and JS. I am trying to learn "findOne". I created a collection. Its name is "Rezervasyon" and there is a field "rezervasyonnumarasi" in this collection. I want to make this, if record exist, write console:"yes" otherwise "no". I am sharing my code. What is wrong with my code?

rezervasyon.js

```
 Template.content.events({
'click #rezervasyonsorgula': function(e, template) {
 var sorgu = template.$('#rezno').val();
 result = Rezervasyon.findOne({rezervasyonnumarasi:sorgu});
 if (result)
  {
  console.log("yes");
  }
 else {
  console.log("no");
      }

 }
});
```

content.html

```
<p id='sorgusonuc'></p>
 <form class="form-vertical pull-right">
      <div class="form-group">
       <span class="f-s-20 text-black">Rezervazyon         Sorgula</span>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <input name="bulten" type="text" class="form-control 
          width-250 m-  auto" id="rezno" placeholder="Rezervasyon Kodunuz">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-theme width-250" id="rezervasyonsorgula" >Sorgula</button>
        </div>
   </form>
```

Thank you for all helps.

Comment: Are you sure that `sorgu` is properly filled (i.e. `console.log(sorgu);` is a string)?

Comment: If you mean the type of field,it is an integer field.

Comment: First rule of being new to JavaScript is you do not speak about Java. JavaScript is not about Java. JavaScript is about "How to fail to pick a meaningful name", not Java. You should [edit] that part out. Please.

Comment: Aha, then you might want to put it through [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) before trying to fetch your `Rezervasyon` document. If not, you will be looking for a string where an integer is stored.

Comment: Sorry I wrote hurry so I missed,i have edited it,Thank you for your attention-Kyll

Comment: will you help me about issue or  continue to looking the details-Kyll

Comment: Always the details first. I have troubles understanding what is wrong with your code. What didn't work? What effect did you expect, what effect did you obtain? You should always post the full description of the issue for us to understand it.

Comment: The style of your writing was not good.we are not in "Fight Club",first rule of...,anyway thank you for helps.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your HTML code is encapsulate in a template element ?

```
 <template name="content">
     <p id='sorgusonuc'></p>
     <form class="form-vertical pull-right">
     ...
 </template>
```

With findOne, you can :

```
Rezervasyon.findOne(); // Return a random element
Rezervasyon.findOne(_byId); // Search by mongo _id
var option = {param: value};
Rezervasyon.findOne(option); // Search with a more complex query
```

findOne return "undefined" or an object

You can also use find() and iterate over the returned array, which can be empty or with elements inside.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.Thank you for all helps.I am sharing code.

```
Template.content.events({
'click #rezervasyonsorgula': function(e, template) {
 var sorgu = template.$('#rezno').val();
 var opt=Rezervasyon.findOne({rezervasyonnumarasi:parseInt(sorgu)});
 if(opt)
  {
   console.log('yes');
  }
 else 
  {
   console.log('no');
  }
 }

 }

 });
```